# Is it possible to have Perl scripts directly message one another, and if so, how is this done?

Tags: perl, ipc, message-queue, messaging

Have Perl scripts that are messaging each other via a database, but wondering if there's a way to have them talk to each other directly -- and if so, how? If it matters, both these scripts are running on one server, and one could start the other.

**UPDATE:** 
Related questions -- " [ipc + perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipc+perl) " tagged questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`perldoc`[`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

In general the whole topic can be summed up under the long-standing UNIX topic of [IPC: Inter-process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 2):

How about a [named pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Named-Pipes)?